# Flutter Firebase - Release APK is different from Debug APK

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

My **Debug** APK works just fine, but the **Release** version is not working properly.

When I Run the **Release** version I get the following Log:

```
I/flutter ( 4054): First Run
I/flutter ( 4054): [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
I/flutter ( 4054): true
I/flutter ( 4054): [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

As you can see here, I do call the `Firebase.initializeApp()` method.

```cpp
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

//Init Firebase Core
//Init App if Firebase Core init is Successfull
class _AppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // Set default `_initialized` and `_error` state to false
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;

  // Define an async function to initialize FlutterFire
  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      // Wait for Firebase to initialize and set `_initialized` state to true
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // Set `_error` state to true if Firebase initialization fails
      print(e);
      setState(() {
        _error = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("First Run");
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Show error message if initialization failed
    if (_error) {
      log("Show error message if initialization failed");
    }

    // Show a loader until FlutterFire is initialized
    if (!_initialized) {
      //return Loading();
      log("Show Loader");
    }

    return MaterialApp(title: "Delorean", theme: _buildTheme(), home: SplashScreen());
  }
}
```

My `flutter doctor -v` returns with no errors. I'm using *Build Gradle version 3.5.3*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the `initializeFlutterFire()` method in the `_AppState` Class.

I called Firebase in the `main` method before `runApp(MyApp)`.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //Allows to call binary libs before runApp 
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Now the **APK Release** works fine.